# sed + does not work on solaris

Tags: regex, sed, solaris

I try to use a `sed` line with a `+` on a Solaris machine and on a Linux machine.

on Solaris sed does not remove the strings until the first number like I want:

```
   solaris:/ ROOT > echo "Release............5.3.7.1-12"  | sed 's/[^0-9]\+//'

   Release............5.3.7.1-12
```

on Linux I get the expected results:

```
  linux tmp]# echo "Linux Release............5.3.7.1-12"  | sed 's/[^0-9]\+//'

  5.3.7.1-12
```

- Why is this sed syntax not working on Solaris?
- What do I need to change in the syntax in order for it to run on Solaris?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, escaping the `+` character (`\+`) results in a literal `+`, not a modifier. This is not the case with `sed` on Ubuntu 10.04, but it might not be on Solaris.

My best guess it that this is implementation-specific, so `sed 's/[^0-9]\+//'` might work.

You could also try `sed -r 's/[^0-9]\+//'` (where `-r` means *extended regular expressions*). It works on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be correct - it's just that the solaris sed doesn't support '+'. the same question by the same author here seems to have more info : http://serverfault.com/questions/348490/sed-not-work-on-solaris